# Annyang.js works in test but after that it doesn't seem to connect

Tags: javascript, function, microphone, annyang

I've tested Annyang in a blank file first. This worked fine, but when I connected the same code to a function in another file it didn't seem te be working. It seemed that the annyang was not connected anymore. The browser didn't ask for permission to use the microphone neither was the red circle visible. However, I've connected it the same way I did while testing.

function: playerRotate(1); I want to start when the user says: turn.

Below you can find my code:

The javascript `

```
$( document ).ready( doStuff );

function doStuff()
{

if (annyang) {

  var commands = {
    'turn': function() {
        playerRotate(1);
        console.log("You said turn");
    }
  };

  annyang.addCommands(commands);
 annyang.debug(true);

annyang.start({ continuous: false });
}


annyang.setLanguage('en-GB');
```

This is the scripttag that I've put in the head of the hmtl: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/annyang/1.1.0/annyang.min.js"></script>`

And I've put the script tag for the main javascript file at the bottom of the body of the html.

Can anyone help to find what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: You are missing a closing curly bracket in your sample code.

If that's not the problem, it could be helpful if you provide a full working code sample including all of your code. Perhaps in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. Unfortunately it wasn't the curly bracket. I added a fully code in a gist https://gist.github.com/phonecase/11c26b07a215f114b85e2cfe59aa2c5c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded your source code and it ran without a hitch (see image below).

Is there something else different between how you ran annyang in your test when it worked and how you ran it later?

My guess would be that what changed was how you ran it locally. Perhaps one of those times you opened it as `file://` and another as `http://localhost` or even `http://my-local-environment` or something similar. Speech Recognition requires HTTPS (or on some versions it can run over HTTP if your host name is localhost). Your safest bet would be to try running it over SSL (even locally, without a valid certificate).

Another option is that you may have blocked speech recognition once and the browser remembers that choice (your mileage may vary depending on browser and version).

As for the code itself, it works great:

[image: Tetris with speech recognition]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering again. You were right it was the way how I ran it. When I ran it over SSL it worked again. Thanks for your time!